# Try removing the code, or fixing the code before it so that it can be reached

Tags: flutter

i am trying toggle btw two pages when i run this code but am getting an error of dead code on : PageB(). Whats wrong with the code, cant seem to see it

```
bool isPageA = true;
      

      return Scaffold(
      body: isPageA ? PageA() : PageB(),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isPageA = true;
              });
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.swap_horiz),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,50),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isPageA = false;
                });
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.swap_vert),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

here are the classes for page a and page b, i want to toogle between page A and B when i click the buttons

```
class PageA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<PageA> createState() => _PageAState();
}

class _PageAState extends State<PageA> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("This is Page A"),
    );
  }
}

class PageB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<PageB> createState() => _PageBState();
}

class _PageBState extends State<PageB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("This is Page B"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working Correctly

Comment: Variable `isPageA` should be defined outside of the `build` method

Comment: @AnteBule thank you , placed it outside and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try below code with full Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool isPageA = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: isPageA ? PageA() : PageB(),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isPageA = true;
              });
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.swap_horiz),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 50),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isPageA = false;
                });
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.swap_vert),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<PageA> createState() => _PageAState();
}

class _PageAState extends State<PageA> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("This is Page A"),
    );
  }
}

class PageB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<PageB> createState() => _PageBState();
}

class _PageBState extends State<PageB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("This is Page B"),
    );
  }
}
```